# Como esconder um componente no Angular 7 ao clicar em um botão dentro de um modal?

Tags: angular

A partir de um botão dentro do componente header estou chamando um modal do Angular Material, neste modal tem um botão entrar, eu precisaria que ao clicar nesse botão um componente chamado banner ficasse escondido.

meu app.component.html tem essa estrutura:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<app-banner></app-banner>
```

o modal.component.html tem essa estrutura:

```html
<p class="title">
  Entrar
  <span class="close" mat-raised-button (click)="save()"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></span>
</p>
  <form class="dialog-enter">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <input type="text" placeholder="E-mail ou número de telefone" />
          <p class="alert">Informe um e-mail ou número de telefone válido.</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Senha" />
            <p class="alert">A senha deve ter entre 4 e 60 caracteres.</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <button class="enter">Entrar</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="remember">
            <mat-checkbox>Lembrar de mim</mat-checkbox>
        </td>
        <td class="help">
          <a href="javascript:void">Precisa de ajuda?</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <p class="title">Novo por aqui?</p>
          <button class="buy">Assine agora!</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
```

Esse é o link do projeto: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ewo6xo

Alguém poderia por favor me ajudar?

Comment: vc pode usar um ngIf baseado numa propriedade.

Comment: Pode me apontar um exemplo por favor?

Comment: Existe algum link que eu possa consultar?

Comment: Se vc quer so esconder pode usar o jquery para adicionar display:none ao style no evento click do botão

Answer (score -1):

Para resolver isso você vai precisar fazer um EventEmitter para o componente pai, onde os componentes app-header e e app-banner estão inseridos.

O EventEmitter consegue externar, através de event biding(no seu caso do botão) informações para o component pai. Com isso você pode utilizar o ngIf para controlar a exibição do banner.

[Aqui você pode ver como utilizar o EventEmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter)

Comment: Tudo bem Anderson! Inseri o link da estrutura do projeto, você pode por favor demonstrar o que escreveu no código? Comecei a estudar Angular faz poucos dias.

Comment: Cara, está complicado mexer no codigo. Mesmo sem mexer vi que o codigo está quebrando. Alem disso você está usando JQuery para controlar a logica dos components. O angular é totalmente capaz de gerenciar os recursos sem necessidade do JQuery. Você pode começar dando uma olhada no conceito de property e event binding. Isso vai eliminar totalmente seu codigo JQuery nos componentes.

Comment: Coloquei o código só para exemplificar o que deve ser feito, não esta completo, por isso quebra. Então sou web designer, conheço bastante o jQuery, por isso implementei algumas pequenas coisas com ele.

Comment: Você poderia por favor inserir os códigos para que eu possa estuda-los?

Comment: Vou montar um mini projeto e coloco no Git para você dar uma olhada. Assim que terminar coloco o link aqui

Comment: muito obrigado Anderson! Fico no aguardo

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse projeto: https://github.com/macedo123/ProjetoAngular1.git

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89031/discussion-between-anderson-macedo-and-munir-baarini).